# $(A \Rightarrow B \land \neg C) \land \neg(A \Rightarrow D) \Rightarrow \neg (B \Rightarrow D \lor C)$ is tautology, contradiction, or a satisfiable?

Tags: propositional-calculus

All this step should be correct

$(A \Rightarrow B \land \neg C) \land \neg(A \Rightarrow D) \Rightarrow \neg (B \Rightarrow D \lor C)$

$(\neg A \lor (B \land \neg C)) \land \neg(\neg A \lor D) \Rightarrow \neg (\neg B \lor D \lor C)$

$(\neg A \lor (B \land \neg C)) \land (A \land \neg D) \Rightarrow (B \land \neg D \land \neg C)$

$\neg ((\neg A \lor (B \land \neg C)) \land (A \land \neg D)) \lor (B \land \neg D \land \neg C)$

$\neg (\neg A \lor (B \land \neg C)) \lor \neg (A \land \neg D) \lor (B \land \neg D \land \neg C)$

$(A \land \neg (B \land \neg C)) \lor (\neg A \lor D) \lor (B \land \neg D \land \neg C)$

$(A \land (\neg B \lor C)) \lor (\neg A \lor D) \lor (B \land \neg D \land \neg C)$

$(A \land \neg  B) \lor (A  \land C) \lor (\neg A \lor D) \lor (B \land \neg D \land \neg C)$

How to continue?

Comment: You could use some parentheses to remove ambiguity...

Comment: Using [SymPy Live](http://live.sympy.org), `a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d'); Phi = ((a >> (b & Not(c))) & Not(a >> d)) >> Not(b >> (d | c)); print simplify(Phi)` produces `True`. It's a **tautology**.

Comment: What are the next steps to my solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is a *tautology*; we can derive with *Natural Deduction* : $¬(B⇒D∨C)$ from premises : $(A⇒B∧¬C)$ and $¬(A⇒D)$ and then use $\to$-intro and *soundness*.

1) $A \to (B∧¬C)$ --- premise

2) $¬(A \to D)$ --- premise

3) $B \to (D∨C)$ --- assumed [a]

4) $A$ --- assumed [b]

5) $B∧¬C$ --- $\to$-elim

6) $¬C$ --- $\land$-elim

7) $B$ --- $\land$-elim

8) $D∨C$ --- $\to$-elim

9) $D$ --- by [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) (it is derivable in a sub-proof with $\lor$-elim)

10) $A \to D$ --- $\to$-intro, discharging [b]

11) contradiction ! --- from 2) and 10)

> 12) $\lnot (B \to (D∨C))$ --- from 3) and 11) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [a].

---

We can check it also with [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) deriving the *empty clause* ($\square$) from the conjunctive normal form of the three clauses :

1) $¬A∨(B∧¬C)$

2) $¬(¬A∨D)$

3) $¬B∨D∨C$.

Comment: I don't understand how continue to prove that the proposition is a tautology

Comment: @Math81 - your approach is terribly long ... You have to go on with distributivity until you arrive at a very very long disjunction with some term of the form : $X \lor \lnot X$. This is TRUE and a disjunction with at least one disjunct TRUE is TRUE.

Comment: You are right: my approach is to long. I need something very elementary to read to understand a more efficient approach. What i can read?

Comment: Please could you show me all the steps using "Natural Deduction"?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that for a assignment d this is not true then 
$(A\implies B \land \neg C) \land \neg(A\implies D)$ should be true and $\neg(B\implies D\lor C)$ should be false.

From the first one we can easily deduce that A is true, D is false,B is true and C is false but then $\neg(B\implies D\lor C)$ is true so contradiction. 
Therefore is tautology.